# Newsticker failure: (wrong-type-argument listp \.\.\.)

Tags: debugging

Suddenly newsticker is failing to load. I get the following stack trace on error. I have made no recent upgrades.

```
Debugger entered: Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp \.\.\.)
newsticker--stat-num-items(Bus\\ Driver\\ Diaries new immortal)
apply(newsticker--stat-num-items Bus\\ Driver\\ Diaries (new immortal))
newsticker--stat-num-items-for-group(Bus\\ Driver\\ Diaries new immortal)
newsticker--treeview-tree-get-tag("Bus Driver Diaries" nil "feeds-4")
#f(compiled-function (g) #<bytecode 0x2370c3d>)("Bus Driver Diaries")
mapcar(#f(compiled-function (g) #<bytecode 0x2370c3d>) ("Sacha Chua" "Good Questions" "Quote of the day" "Tory C Anderson" "Bus Driver Diaries" "Dadacity" "Austen Knows Best" "Every Day Miracles" "Vi Hart" "Brain Pickings" "Inside Clojure" "Reddit Clojure" "Reddit Emacs" "Reddit Postgres" "Reddit Programming Languages"))
newsticker--treeview-tree-expand((tree-widget :args nil :expander newsticker&#x2013;treeview-tree-expand :tag #("Feeds" 0 5 (mouse-face highlight help-echo "Feeds" :nt-vfeed nil :nt-feed nil :nt-id "feeds" keymap (keymap (13 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (10 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (mouse-3 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click) (mouse-1 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click)) face newsticker-treeview-face)) :expander-p #f(compiled-function (&rest \_) #<bytecode 0x204a4dd>) :leaf-icon newsticker&#x2013;tree-widget-leaf-icon :nt-group ("Sacha Chua" "Good Questions" "Quote of the day" "Tory C Anderson" "Bus Driver Diaries" "Dadacity" "Austen Knows Best" "Every Day Miracles" "Vi Hart" "Brain Pickings" "Inside Clojure" "Reddit Clojure" "Reddit Emacs" "Reddit Postgres" "Reddit Programming Languages") :nt-id "feeds" :keep (:nt-id) :open t :node (item :tag #("Feeds" 0 5 (mouse-face highlight help-echo "Feeds" :nt-vfeed nil :nt-feed nil :nt-id "feeds" keymap (keymap (13 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (10 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (mouse-3 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click) (mouse-1 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click)) face newsticker-treeview-face)))))
widget-apply((tree-widget :args nil :expander newsticker&#x2013;treeview-tree-expand :tag #("Feeds" 0 5 (mouse-face highlight help-echo "Feeds" :nt-vfeed nil :nt-feed nil :nt-id "feeds" keymap (keymap (13 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (10 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (mouse-3 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click) (mouse-1 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click)) face newsticker-treeview-face)) :expander-p #f(compiled-function (&rest \_) #<bytecode 0x204a4dd>) :leaf-icon newsticker&#x2013;tree-widget-leaf-icon :nt-group ("Sacha Chua" "Good Questions" "Quote of the day" "Tory C Anderson" "Bus Driver Diaries" "Dadacity" "Austen Knows Best" "Every Day Miracles" "Vi Hart" "Brain Pickings" "Inside Clojure" "Reddit Clojure" "Reddit Emacs" "Reddit Postgres" "Reddit Programming Languages") :nt-id "feeds" :keep (:nt-id) :open t :node (item :tag #("Feeds" 0 5 (mouse-face highlight help-echo "Feeds" :nt-vfeed nil :nt-feed nil :nt-id "feeds" keymap (keymap (13 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (10 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (mouse-3 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click) (mouse-1 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click)) face newsticker-treeview-face)))) :expander)
tree-widget-value-create((tree-widget :args nil :expander newsticker&#x2013;treeview-tree-expand :tag #("Feeds" 0 5 (mouse-face highlight help-echo "Feeds" :nt-vfeed nil :nt-feed nil :nt-id "feeds" keymap (keymap (13 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (10 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (mouse-3 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click) (mouse-1 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click)) face newsticker-treeview-face)) :expander-p #f(compiled-function (&rest \_) #<bytecode 0x204a4dd>) :leaf-icon newsticker&#x2013;tree-widget-leaf-icon :nt-group ("Sacha Chua" "Good Questions" "Quote of the day" "Tory C Anderson" "Bus Driver Diaries" "Dadacity" "Austen Knows Best" "Every Day Miracles" "Vi Hart" "Brain Pickings" "Inside Clojure" "Reddit Clojure" "Reddit Emacs" "Reddit Postgres" "Reddit Programming Languages") :nt-id "feeds" :keep (:nt-id) :open t :node (item :tag #("Feeds" 0 5 (mouse-face highlight help-echo "Feeds" :nt-vfeed nil :nt-feed nil :nt-id "feeds" keymap (keymap (13 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (10 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (mouse-3 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click) (mouse-1 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click)) face newsticker-treeview-face)))))
widget-apply((tree-widget :args nil :expander newsticker&#x2013;treeview-tree-expand :tag #("Feeds" 0 5 (mouse-face highlight help-echo "Feeds" :nt-vfeed nil :nt-feed nil :nt-id "feeds" keymap (keymap (13 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (10 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (mouse-3 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click) (mouse-1 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click)) face newsticker-treeview-face)) :expander-p #f(compiled-function (&rest \_) #<bytecode 0x204a4dd>) :leaf-icon newsticker&#x2013;tree-widget-leaf-icon :nt-group ("Sacha Chua" "Good Questions" "Quote of the day" "Tory C Anderson" "Bus Driver Diaries" "Dadacity" "Austen Knows Best" "Every Day Miracles" "Vi Hart" "Brain Pickings" "Inside Clojure" "Reddit Clojure" "Reddit Emacs" "Reddit Postgres" "Reddit Programming Languages") :nt-id "feeds" :keep (:nt-id) :open t :node (item :tag #("Feeds" 0 5 (mouse-face highlight help-echo "Feeds" :nt-vfeed nil :nt-feed nil :nt-id "feeds" keymap (keymap (13 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (10 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (mouse-3 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click) (mouse-1 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click)) face newsticker-treeview-face)))) :value-create)
widget-default-create((tree-widget :args nil :expander newsticker&#x2013;treeview-tree-expand :tag #("Feeds" 0 5 (mouse-face highlight help-echo "Feeds" :nt-vfeed nil :nt-feed nil :nt-id "feeds" keymap (keymap (13 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (10 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (mouse-3 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click) (mouse-1 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click)) face newsticker-treeview-face)) :expander-p #f(compiled-function (&rest \_) #<bytecode 0x204a4dd>) :leaf-icon newsticker&#x2013;tree-widget-leaf-icon :nt-group ("Sacha Chua" "Good Questions" "Quote of the day" "Tory C Anderson" "Bus Driver Diaries" "Dadacity" "Austen Knows Best" "Every Day Miracles" "Vi Hart" "Brain Pickings" "Inside Clojure" "Reddit Clojure" "Reddit Emacs" "Reddit Postgres" "Reddit Programming Languages") :nt-id "feeds" :keep (:nt-id) :open t :node (item :tag #("Feeds" 0 5 (mouse-face highlight help-echo "Feeds" :nt-vfeed nil :nt-feed nil :nt-id "feeds" keymap (keymap (13 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (10 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (mouse-3 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click) (mouse-1 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click)) face newsticker-treeview-face)))))
widget-apply((tree-widget :args nil :expander newsticker&#x2013;treeview-tree-expand :tag #("Feeds" 0 5 (mouse-face highlight help-echo "Feeds" :nt-vfeed nil :nt-feed nil :nt-id "feeds" keymap (keymap (13 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (10 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (mouse-3 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click) (mouse-1 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click)) face newsticker-treeview-face)) :expander-p #f(compiled-function (&rest \_) #<bytecode 0x204a4dd>) :leaf-icon newsticker&#x2013;tree-widget-leaf-icon :nt-group ("Sacha Chua" "Good Questions" "Quote of the day" "Tory C Anderson" "Bus Driver Diaries" "Dadacity" "Austen Knows Best" "Every Day Miracles" "Vi Hart" "Brain Pickings" "Inside Clojure" "Reddit Clojure" "Reddit Emacs" "Reddit Postgres" "Reddit Programming Languages") :nt-id "feeds" :keep (:nt-id) :open t :node (item :tag #("Feeds" 0 5 (mouse-face highlight help-echo "Feeds" :nt-vfeed nil :nt-feed nil :nt-id "feeds" keymap (keymap (13 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (10 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (mouse-3 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click) (mouse-1 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click)) face newsticker-treeview-face)))) :create)
widget-create(tree-widget :tag #("Feeds" 0 5 (mouse-face highlight help-echo "Feeds" :nt-vfeed nil :nt-feed nil :nt-id "feeds" keymap (keymap (13 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (10 . newsticker-treeview-tree-do-click) (mouse-3 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click) (mouse-1 . newsticker-treeview-tree-click)) face newsticker-treeview-face)) :expander newsticker&#x2013;treeview-tree-expand :expander-p #f(compiled-function (&rest \_) #<bytecode 0x204a4dd>) :leaf-icon newsticker&#x2013;tree-widget-leaf-icon :nt-group ("Sacha Chua" "Good Questions" "Quote of the day" "Tory C Anderson" "Bus Driver Diaries" "Dadacity" "Austen Knows Best" "Every Day Miracles" "Vi Hart" "Brain Pickings" "Inside Clojure" "Reddit Clojure" "Reddit Emacs" "Reddit Postgres" "Reddit Programming Languages") :nt-id "feeds" :keep (:nt-id) :open t)
newsticker&#x2013;treeview-tree-update()
newsticker&#x2013;treeview-buffer-init()
newsticker-treeview()
newsticker-show-news()
funcall-interactively(newsticker-show-news)
call-interactively(newsticker-show-news nil nil)
command-execute(newsticker-show-news)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that one of the blogspot blogs on my list, which I'd followed for a while previously, had started to require password authentication (and I didn't know the password). Some result of caching was that it was breaking the whole system. Here was the solution:

1. Remove the offending blog from `newsticker-url-list` (which I defined via customize, in my custom file).
2. Remove the Newsticker cache folder for me located `~/emacs/emacs.d/newsticker/`. I renamed the directory to `newsticker_bak` so I could recover if necessary.

Now I restarted emacs and everything was happy again.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. I am intrigued that you find Newsticker still useful. I used to use it but moved to gnus. There is also elfeed.

Comment: @m43cap I moved to Newsticker FROM gnus because there were format Gnus couldn't read well (Atom) and it was slow; Newsticker generally does its job well. I chose it over elfeed because it is included with Emacs.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.